# Spring Security 4 Concurrency Control, want to use authentication-error-url both for wrong login or user already logged

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on a spring-based project;
For the user login interface I am using Spring Security 4.0.3;
Everything is fine on the concurrency control, but I would like to obtain a custom error message when the user tries to log in another time and the session of the previous logging is not expired.
For the remember me issue it is fixed, since it uses `session-authentication-error-url="/login?auth_error` 
But for a multiple logging from form it redirects to the url specified at `<form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/"

   authentication-failure-url="/login?error" />`
That is the same used for a wrong username or password.
Since I use the param specified in the url to send an error when redirecting, how could I do to send the user to a page like `/login?different_error` ?
Session management in `spring-security.xml`

```
<session-management invalid-session-url="/login?invalid" 
session-authentication-error-url="/login?auth_error">
    <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
</session-management>
```

Listener in `web.xml`

```
<listener-class>
  org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
</listener-class>
```

Log-in controller method

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout,
            @RequestParam(value = "invalid", required = false) String invalid,
            @RequestParam(value = "auth_error", required = false) String auth_error) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        if (error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", "Username e/o password non validi!");
        }
            if (logout != null) {
                model.addObject("msg", "Hai effettuato il logout!");
            }
            if (invalid != null) {
                model.addObject("error", "invalid session ID");
              }
        if (auth_error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", "Utente già loggato nel sistema");
        }
        model.setViewName("login");

        return model;

    }
```

Thanks, any help would be really appreciated.

Edit: user logout is also detected as an invalid session

Answer (score 0):

Just to input here; You can set an attribute say ("secondlogin",true);
Then on jsp page you can display custom message based on that attribute.